# Group objects by two properties in using groupBy() in Java 8

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors, groupingby

I have a Person class like below:

```
public class Person {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int score;

    // constructor, getters, etc.
}
```

And I have a list of `Persone` objects and I want to group them into a `Map`.

*Main class:*

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person1 = new Person(1, "John", 4);
        Person person2 = new Person(2, "John", 3);
        Person person3 = new Person(2, "John", 4);

        List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
        personList.add(person1);
        personList.add(person2);
        personList.add(person3);

        Map<String, List<Person>> personByName = personList.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(Person::getName));

        System.out.println(personByName);
    }

}
```

It gives the result:

```
{John=[Person{id=1, name='John', score=4},
       Person{id=2, name='John', score=3},
       Person{id=2, name='John', score=4}]}
```

How can I group by person `name`, but still distinguish two people by `id` by keeping them separatelly inside the map?

I want the result to look like this:

```
{John=[Person{id=1, name='John', score=4}],
 John=[Person{id=2, name='John', score=3}, Person{id=2, name='John', score=4}]}
```

Comment: You can’t. The result is a `Map` and maps can’t have duplicate keys. If you want different group criteria than the name strings, you need a different key type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I group by person `name`, but still distinguish two people by `id` by keeping them separatelly inside the map?

It's inherently **impossible** to have two identical *keys* in a `Map`.

But there are some options to group the data in such a way.

<sup>**Note:** ID is usually expected to be unique, but in your example it's not, so I will blind on it. Although we might use *score* as the second property for grouping, I'll proceed with grouping person objects by ID</sup>

To group people by `name` and then by `id` you can create a nested map `Map<String,Map<Integer,List<Person>>>`, which will associate each unique `name` with a map that allows to retrieve a having a particular `id` (and obviously the same name).

That's how it might be implemented:

```
 List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(personList,               // with Java 9+ use List.of() instead
    new Person(1, "John", 4),
    new Person(2, "John", 3),
    new Person(2, "John", 4)
);

Map<String, Map<Integer, List<Person>>> personByNameAndId = personList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Person::getName,
        Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getId)
    ));
        
personByNameAndId.forEach((name, personById) -> {
    System.out.println(name);
    personById.forEach((id, people) -> people.forEach(p -> System.out.println("id " + id + " -> " + p)));
});
```

*Output:*

```
John
id 1 -> Person{id=1, name='John', score=4}
id 2 -> Person{id=2, name='John', score=3}
id 2 -> Person{id=2, name='John', score=4}
```

It's worth to mention that it's advisable to avoid using nested collections because they are cumbersome and you might introduce a bug if you're not attentive enough when dialing with. For example, with map of maps, you can accidentally swap the order of *keys* while invoking `get()`, and because `Map.get()` expects an argument of type `Object` the code would still compile.

Another option would be to introduce an object that would hold the `name` and `id` of a person. It can be implemented either as a *class* (which would be the only option with Java 8):

```
public class IdName {
    private final int id;
    private final String name;
    
    public IdName(Person p) {
        this(p.getId(), p.getName());
    }
    
    // getters, all-args-constructor, equals/hashcode
}
```

Or as a Java 16 [*record*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/language/records.html):

```
public record IdName(int id, String name) {
    public IdName(Person p) {
        this(p.getId(), p.getName());
    }
}
```

In order to facilitate convention `Person` into `IdName` you can introduce either a constructor of `IdName` which expects an instance of `Person` (as shown above), or convenience method `toIdName()` in the `Person` class.

That how to group people using this custom object, a *key* and retrieve from the map a `List<Person>` that share `name` and `id` with the given person:

```
Map<IdName, List<Person>> personByNameAndId = personList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(IdName::new));

Person john = new Person(2, "John", 0);
personByNameAndId.get(new IdName(john))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output:*

```
Person{id=2, name='John', score=3}
Person{id=2, name='John', score=4}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is the one I find most helpful so i accepted it.

Answer (score 2):

> **groupingBy()** convert **List** to **Map<String,List>** , **key = John , Value = List .**
>
> **toMap()** convert **List** to **Map<String,Person>** , **Key = John , value = Person , The key in Map cannot be repeated, so the name must be changed.**

```
Person person1 = new Person(1, "John1", 4);
Person person2 = new Person(2, "John2", 3);
Person person3 = new Person(2, "John3", 4);

List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
personList.add(person1);
personList.add(person2);
personList.add(person3);


Map<String, Person> personByName = personList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getName,Function.identity()));

System.out.println(personByName);
```

Output :

```
{John1=Person(id=1, name=John1, score=4), John2=Person(id=2, name=John2, score=3), John3=Person(id=2, name=John3, score=4)}
```